# Row to column conversion

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table like below

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   AA  a   b   c   d
2   BB  e   f   g   h
```

I want the result to be like below

```
1   AA  C   a
1   AA  D   b
1   AA  E   c
1   AA  F   d
2   BB  C   e
2   BB  D   f
2   BB  E   g
2   BB  F   h
```

I tried using Unpivot option but i could not do this ?

How can i do this using SQL / C# or using Linq ?

Can any one help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNPIVOT workes fine for me with your data

```
declare @x table 
(
   A int,
   B varchar(2),
   C varchar,
   D varchar,
   E varchar,
   F varchar
)

insert into @x
values
(1, 'AA', 'a','b','v','d'),
(2, 'BB', 'e','f','g','h')

SELECT A,B,Col as C,letter as a
FROM 
   (SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F
   FROM @x) p
UNPIVOT
   (Letter FOR Col IN 
      (C,D,E,F)
)AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked @Ash's answer but I do love CROSS APPLY

```
with data(a, b, c, d, e, f) as (
    select 1, 'AA', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' union all
    select 2, 'BB', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
)

select a, b, s.* 
from data
cross apply (
    values  
        ('C', c), 
        ('D', d), 
        ('E', e), 
        ('F', f)
) s(C1, C2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done in ANSI Standard SQL via `UNION ALL`, but some casting may be required if the original columns being pivoted do not share the same data type.

```
SELECT A, B, 'C' AS ColName, C AS ColValue FROM theTable
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'D' AS ColName, D AS ColValue FROM theTable
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'E' AS ColName, E AS ColValue FROM theTable
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'F' AS ColName, F AS ColValue FROM theTable
;
```

The query shown above will not suppress NULL values in the columns being un-pivoted, but that can be changed by adding the necessary predicate to the `WHERE` clause of each query in the union:

```
SELECT A, B, 'C' AS ColName, C AS ColValue FROM theTable WHERE C IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'D' AS ColName, D AS ColValue FROM theTable WHERE D IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'E' AS ColName, E AS ColValue FROM theTable WHERE E IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, 'F' AS ColName, F AS ColValue FROM theTable WHERE F IS NOT NULL
;
```

It's also possible to filter out NULLs by issuing a `SELECT` against a subquery:

```
SELECT A, B, ColName, ColValue FROM (
    SELECT A, B, 'C' AS ColName, C AS ColValue FROM theTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B, 'D' AS ColName, D AS ColValue FROM theTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B, 'E' AS ColName, E AS ColValue FROM theTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B, 'F' AS ColName, F AS ColValue FROM theTable
) AS unpivotedTable WHERE ColValue IS NOT NULL
;
```